# Treeview enabled false

Tags: c#, telerik

If the enable property of a Rad Treeview assigned to false, user cannot walk into nodes.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/databindings/defaultcs.aspx

For example, one should not select/unselect any node but one can walk into all nodes. How can I do it? 
Are there any property for it?

Edit: The treeview's enabled property should be false but user can walk into sports etc..
[image: The treeview's enabled property should be false but user can walk into sports etc..]

Comment: a simple approach is to unselect it in the selectionChanged-Event

Answer (score 0):

Set IsEnabled property for each item to false.
After that user can't edit their values.

See: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreeview/features/treeview-item/feautres-treeviewitem-enable-disable-items